# Babel compile path with wildcard but keep folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Hi I am testing how can I give path with wildcards to babel and output the same structure.

```
|src
|---A
|-----src
|-----------a.js
|---B
|-----src
|-----------b.js
```

If I run `babel root/**/src -d lib/**/lib`, it will output

```
|lib
|---**
|-----lib
|-----------a.js
|-----------b.js
```

However, what I want is,

```
|lib
|---A
|-----lib
|-----------a.js
|---B
|-----lib
|-----------b.js
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The babel cli can't quite do this. It can get close with the `--relative` option:

```
babel src/*/src --out-dir ../lib --relative
```

However this doesn't rename the top directory; you'll end up with a structure like the following in the original root directory:

```
|src
|---A
|-----lib
|-----------a.js
|-----src
|-----------a.js
|---B
|-----lib
|-----------b.js
|-----src
|-----------b.js
```

If you really need the final structure, you could follow this up with some bash `cp -R src lib; rm -rf lib/*/src`. Or with rsync `rsync -r --exclude='src/*/src' src lib`. Or, instead of using `--relative` above, compile each package separately with `ls src | xargs -I{} babel src/{}/src -d lib/{}/lib`

If you really want to do this in a single step you'll probably have to use a tool like Gulp, or write a script with the babel API directly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, ur solution is perfect!